How does a remote controller know which button was pressed?
I disassembled one of my remotes to see what's inside, and saw that lines connected to different buttons connect to each other also. Whenever I use buttons in my own circuits, I connect each button to one of the input pins of the MCU and the other side to GND.
I also looked up this circuit, where I see multiple lines from different buttons are connected to each other. I'm trying to understand how the signalling works, and how the IC figures out which button was pressed.
I'm using the following schematic (from www.raypcb.com) to try and understand this:


Is the question about how the 555 IC shown in the schematic of a IR transmitter knows which button is pressed, or how the IR receiver (not shown) detects which button was pressed?

The 555 is a timer/oscillator IC.  It uses R2 and a capacitor to set the frequency of the ocillator.  Pressing a button connects one of the capacitors to the oscillator, causing it to run at a particular frequency.
If you press two buttons at once, you get both capacitors connected which results in a frequency lower than either button alone.
Your example circuit is not a good example.  No commercially made remote control would use this circuit.
Normal remote controls have buttons connected in a matrix like the one shown here.

Here's how to read the matrix to see which button was pressed:

Set all the row pins to low (0V.)
Set R1 to high (5V.)
Check all the column (C) pins to see if one of them reads 5V.
If you find a column pin with a high signal, then you know which button was pressed (row 1 and the column you read.)
If none of the column pins is high, then you set the row back to low, then go to the next row.  Repeat from step 2 with a different row each time until you find a row and column combination that delivers a high.

This circuit isn't all that good, either.  It can deliver multiple keypresses and fake keypresses.  It is only to illustrate the concept.

Do indcutors play any role in this type of circuit?

Not usually.  A commercial remote control might have some as protection against RF interference.

This controller doesn't, it is dumb.  If you use different values of capacitors for Cz then it will transmit different signals through the IR photo diode.  Whatever receives that IR signal can then decode the signal and determine which button was pressed.

This circuit is known as a astable multivibrator or oscillator

Source
The capacitance c is charged through R2 and R1, and discharged through R2 and the 555 generates an alternating output.
t1 = 0.693(R1+R2)*C
t2 = 0.693(R2*C)
By pushing the buttons you increase the capcitance and therefore the frequency of your IR photodiode.
If all buttons have the same capacitance you can sense how many buttons are pushed. If you have different capacitances you can decode which buttons are being pressed. You will have to decode on the reciever side which button combination will produce the recieved frequency.
